# Xcode 6: Unable to resize textview height without changing the width

Tags: swift, xcode6, uitextview, constraints

I am attempting to resize the height to contain the different text strings but I am having problems with the different width of the textviews at runtime.
When I examine the frame settings at run time the width is less than the constrained width 316. As a result the text is getting cut off. [image]

The scene uses a scrollview with a textview and two buttons embedded. 
There are no visible constraint errors, although there are these warnings "Constraint referencing items turned off in current configuration. Turn off this constraint in the current configuration." I attempted to find any constraints that were incorrect but if I disabled any I immediately get errors. Another user suggested that I should document the constraints but the only way I know how to do that is manually. Another scene with similar configuration works without error.

The code that is causing the problem is:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    var newFrame = textView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    textView.frame = newFrame;
    textView.scrollEnabled = false
}
```

When I pause the code the fixedWidth = 300 (height 200) but the newSize is 293 by 169. It has not kept the fixed width. Is this due to a constraint error or a bug in this code?

Comment: sizeThatFits might return a width different from the initial size... if you want a fixed width you can just leave the width at your custom value.

Comment: Is there any function that does this? I want to adjust the height and leave the width as it is which the way I read it is that sizeThatFits is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I modified the view to confirm its behaviour (after I submitted this question) it started to work correctly. I have absolutely no idea what caused this to work other than I removed the height constraint that I had added to force the height while I tried to get a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use UILabel for static text, simply set [preferredMaxLayoutWidth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/preferredMaxLayoutWidth) to be equal to its width. Then Auto Layout will function correctly because the intrinsicContentSize will be limited to this width, and it will automatically calculate the correct height.

Comment: I am using a UITextView not UILabel. Is there a function for textviews?

Comment: For some reason, when I modified the view to confirm its behaviour after I submitted this question it has started to work correctly. I have absolutely no idea what caused this to work other than I removed the height constraint that I had added to force  the height while I tried to get a solution to the problem.